# Validation errors while CSV upload

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import, data-import-wizard, data-import

Our company has just started the salesforce and we had a demo tool access we are practicing in that demo account.

While loading data we got the following error.

The following import has completed with validation errors

```
Name: 34b98ae2-9dfd-f796-26d3-1ac5c4b6ef02
Description: Import to Upload from Demo_upload.csv file content.
External Key: 64e17930-d47a-40a4-0cf6-8819e87abb0e
Source: Demo_upload_99be3ac7-507c-422c-9a25-71fc8a18f2b4.csv
Destination: Upload
```

Results:

```
Inserted: 1
Updated: 0
```

ValidationErrors:

```
Invalid Number: 21
Invalid Phone: 1
```

Validation results have been logged to a delimited text file and attached to this message.

Comment: What kind of object you want to populate by uploading CSV?

Comment: we have 171 columns and 22 rows

Comment: What object you want to update with the CSV: Is it Account, Contact or any other?
That object has some validation, which is getting failed by the data in CSV

Comment: No, it is not Account or Contact

Comment: Is that a custom object?
You need to check validation rules on that particular object

Comment: What's the question? Phone numbers need to be valid and numbers have to be numbers. "9.99" (a decimal) cannot be imported to a number field, where "9" can. "0499-999-999" can't be imported into a phone field - assuming country code 61, try reformatting your data to "61499999999".

Comment: Then what we should select if we have decimal numbers